Solve one conditional recurrence relation
Recently when learning SICP, Exercise 1.26 exposes one sequence when calculating its complexity (here it is the multiplication count):
$$
D(n)=
    \begin{cases}
      2D(n/2)+1,n\text{ is even}\\
      D(n-1)+1,\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases},n>0\\
D(0)=0
$$
Although schemewiki gives one rough calculation (i.e. $O(\log 2^n)$) by comparing with another recursive call method which is fine for complexity, I want to know how to give one exact formula for the above relation.

When learning Discrete Mathematics, I only solved exercises with no conditional recurrence relation. I also found one QA about conditional recurrence relation, but it is much more complex than the above one.
Then how to solve the above recurrence relation?

Computing the recurrence manually, the first ten terms after $D(0)=0$ are $$1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17$$ This matches to OEIS sequence A092754, which includes the explicit formula $D(n)=2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}+n-1$. (This suggests that it's better to view $n$ in base 2, which is supported by a link to sequence A004754.)

Also, note that this implies $D(n)\leq 2^{\log_2 n}+n-1=2n-1$ which validates the $O(n)$ growth.

@Semiclassical Thanks for your useful reference. 1. How do we relate $D(n)$ with "Numbers n whose binary expansion starts 10." with one useful meaning? 2. As you says "This suggests that it's better to view n in base 2", SICP https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#footnote_Temp_62 uses this idea for the question's companion code where $D(n)=D(n/2)+1,n\text{ is even}$. But here factor $2$ has the different growth rate from the odd number case when recursion. Then how to solve it elegantly?

No idea how one "deduces" the solution, but it isn't too bad to check the recurrence for $D(n)+1$---see my CW.

In that case, what if it wasn't conditional?
Assuming $n$ is odd and sufficiently big:
$$
D(n)=D(n-1)+1 = 2D(\frac{n-1}2)+2
$$
Therefore, for $n\ge 2$:
$$ D(n)= 2D(\lfloor n/2\rfloor )+1+\delta_{n\equiv_2 1}\tag{2}$$
Or alternatively:
$$ D(n)= 2D(\lfloor n/2\rfloor )+1+2(n/2-\lfloor n/2\rfloor)\tag{3}$$
If you now write $n$ in binary, as Semiclassical explained,  formula (2) is easy to interpret using the repeated substitution method.
And using (3) you might be able to deduce the formula using generating functions. Though I'm not sure about this one.

The notation is that of the Kronecker-Delta (though a little modified). That is, if $P$ is a predicate (in our example the predicate is that $n$ modulo 2 is 1):
$$
\delta_{P(x)} = 1 \quad  \text{ if } P(x)   \text{ is true, }\quad \text{and  }0\text{ otherwise}
$$
It is essentially another formalism in which we can write conditional expressions. With some practice, this formalism is often easier to work with. You may know the equivalent indicator set formalism $\delta_{P(x)} = _{\{z\mid P(z)\}}(x)$ instead.
So equation (2) still has the conditional part, but in an easier to work with formalism, while in (3) the conditional expression part   has been reexpressed using functions for which we know quite a lot about.
Regarding formula (2) or (3), go try both cases: $n$ even and $n$ odd, and test whether the formulas give the same result as the original recursion (though for the case $n$ odd, you have to apply the original recursion twice).
Regarding the substitution method: Write $n= 2^{i_1} + ... +2^{i_k}$ with $i_1>...>i_k$. Note that the part $\delta_{n\equiv_2 1}$ then by repeated subtitution at some point outputs $2^{i_k}$, then eventually $2^{i_{k-1}}$, and so on till $2^{i_1}$.
Meanwhile, the summand $+1$ in the formula adds $1$ in the first application, then $2$, and so on.

Thanks for your help. 1. I can understand "using the repeated substitution method", but how to get the exact formula without knowing it in advance? This is why I don't mark Semiclassical's answer as solving my problem. 2. I don't know your notation $\delta_{n\equiv_2 1}$. How is it different from the corresponding part in (3)? IMHO "generating functions" needs all consecutive terms but here you only consider the odd indexed ones.

Thanks. With more info, I understood your method. More detailedly, following "the substitution method",  when $n\ge 2$
$$
\begin{align*}
D(n)&=2(2(\ldots(2D(1)+1+\delta_{(n>>\lfloor\log n-1\rfloor)\equiv_2 1})+\ldots)\
&=2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}D(1)+\overbrace{2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}-1}^{\text{accumulate 1 in }D(n)}+\overbrace{n-2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}}^{\text{accumulate }\delta}\
&=2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}-1+n
\end{align*}
$$
Then $D(0),D(1)$ are checked separately.

Since I don't know how to prove the following results, I'll simply document the OEIS sourcing as a wiki answer. Manually generating the first ten values after $D(0)=0$ yields $$1,3,4,7,8,9,10,15,16,17$$
This matches to OEIS sequence A092754, which includes the explicit formula $$D(n)=2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}+n-1$$
As an aside, this implies $$D(n)\leq 2^{\log_2 n}+n=2n$$ and thus $D(n)=O(\log 2^n)=O(n)$ as the OP's link indicated.
An interesting observation is that, if we instead look at $B(n):=D(n)+1$ (sequence A004754), the first ten values are now
$$2,4,5,8,9,10,11,16,17,18$$
Converting to binary then yields
$$10, 100, 101, 1000,1001,1010,1011,10000,10001,10010$$
so $B(n)$ apparently corresponds to those integers whose binary representation begins with $10$. That every instance of $B(n)$ is of this form is not hard to see: adding $2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$ to $n$ has the effect of replacing the leading $1$ in $n$'s binary representation with $10$, and it appears that this works backwards as well (i.e., replace $10\to 1$.) For completeness, the corresponding recurrence for $B(n)$ can be written as
$$B(0)=1,\quad B(2n)=2B(n),\quad B(2n+1)=B(2n)+1$$
That this always produces $B(n)$ with a leading $10$ in binary is again not hard to see. Moreover, that the above formula for $D(n)$ satisfies this recurrence is readily verified:
$$B(2n)=2^{\lfloor \log_2 (2n)\rfloor}+2n=2^{\lfloor1+ \log_2 n\rfloor}+2n=2^1\cdot 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}+2n=2B(n),$$
$$B(2n+1)=2^{\lfloor \log_2 (2n+1)\rfloor}+2n+1=2^{\lfloor \log_2 (2n)\rfloor}+2n+1=B(n)+1$$ The observation in these cases are basically that $2n$ requires one more binary bit than $n$, whereas $2n+1$ has exactly as many bits as $2n$.


Very elegant and ingenious operation of adding 1. This connects with "companion code" where both manipulate with binary bits.



"Since I don't know how to prove the following results": Here I give one summary of your thought process to help future readers. Here it is appropriate to write some terms of $B(n)$ and then guess its form of "Numbers n whose binary expansion starts 10". Then you find one form $n+2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$ satisfying this property although IMHO it is not easy from scratch.


Then you show it satisfies the recurrence so it is the unique solution where the unique property is ensured by recurrence. This process is not easily generalized to other problems especially finding $n+2^{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}$.

That's a plausible reconstruction of how to proceed, though in my own case I didn't proceed by guessing. Rather, I searched those first 10 values in OEIS.org and found that entry. The rest is largely based on the formulas and links therein.
